# Rails - form_for select that show my categories from db

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-5, ruby-on-rails-6

I have Pages associated to my Categories
Now I have a form that I'm creating Pages

```
<%= form_for @page do |f| %>

<table>
    <tr>
        <td><%= f.label :title %></td>
        <td><%= f.text_field :title %></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><%= f.label :desc %></td>
        <td><%= f.text_field :desc %></td>          
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><%= f.label :category_id %></td>
        <td><%= f.select(Page.all, :category_id, :title) %></td>            
    </tr>           
</table>    

<%= f.submit %> 


<% end %>
```

I'm trying to create a select dropdown that will show me all the categories that I have from my db, after I select one it will assign the Page that I'm creating to the Category that I'm choosing from the select dropdown

Comment: Then what is the problem??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use

```
f.select :category, Category.pluck(:title, :id)
```

Be aware, that if your rails version is lower, that 4.x you can only use [`pluck`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Calculations/pluck) with one column.

Comment: It should be mentioned that before Rails 4, you can only use `pluck` with one column.

Comment: How can I assign the Page that I'm creating to the selected Category while I'm submitting the form?

Comment: @user4571629 it depends on your database design. generally, if `Page belongs_to :category`, then there is a `category_id` column in pages table. thus, you just do `f.select :category_id, Category.pluck(:title, :id)` - it now should do it for you

Comment: Yes, I have the exact relations that you've mentioned, It's not assigning it, I have tried this line: <%= f.select :category_id, Category.pluck(:name, :id) %>

Comment: Make sure you have whitelisted in params the `category_id` etc

Answer (score 1):

You need to change your select tag according to this.

```
<%= form_for @page do |f| %>

<table>
<tr>
    <td><%= f.label :title %></td>
    <td><%= f.text_field :title %></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><%= f.label :desc %></td>
    <td><%= f.text_field :desc %></td>          
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><%= f.label :category %></td>
    <td><%= f.select(:category_id, options_from_collection_for_select(Category.all, :category_id, :title)) %></td>            
</tr>
```

Comment: That shows me the pages, but I want a list of my categories

Answer (score 0):

For ***Rails3***(or may be less), if you've a `Category` model you can simply do.

```
f.select(:category, Category.select([:id,:title]).map { |c| [ c.id, c.title ] } , { include_blank: true })
```

Comment: using Ruby for db processing is very bad idea.

Comment: @AndreyDeineko  I don't know, I do it more often. you've used `pluck` its also `ruby` behind the scenes isn't it... it's just a shorthand method.

Comment: [`pluck`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Calculations/pluck) operates on database. Your solution will load the whole collection of categories prior any calculations, and this can easily lead to memory overload if there are a big collection of caegories

Comment: Yeah I just saw that.. Thanks a lot dude.

Comment: @AndreyDeineko I am more good with **Rails3** and `pluck` is not available in it.. I've updated my code though

Answer (score 0):

[`collection_select`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper/collection_select) is what you need:

```
<%= form_for @page do |f| %>
  <%= f.collection_select :category_id, Category.all, :id, :title %>          
  <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```